# Display content based on id (from database, not html id)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here is what I want to do. I have the following html displaying projects from by db.

```
<div class="col-md-5">
  <ul class="todo-projects-container">
     <li class="todo-padding-b-0">
        <div class="todo-head">
           <button class="btn btn-square btn-sm green todo-bold">Add Project</button>
           <h3>Projects</h3>
           <p>4 Waiting Attention</p>
        </div>
     </li>
     <?php foreach ($projects as $project): ?>
        <li class="todo-projects-item">
          <h3><?php echo $project->project_name ?></h3>
          <p><?php echo $project->project_body ?></p>
          <div class="todo-project-item-foot">
             <p class="todo-red todo-inline">Project #<?php echo $project->project_id ?></p>
             <p class="todo-inline todo-float-r">32 Members
               <a class="todo-add-button" href="#todo-members-modal" data-toggle="modal">+</a>
             </p>
          </div>
        </li>
        <div class="todo-projects-divider"></div>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
  </ul>
</div>
```

When I first load the page, the first project receives the class="active" (using jquery) and whenever a click a project it removes the active class from the previous li and adds to the clicked one. So far so good.

Now I need to display the following:

```
<ul class="todo-tasks-content">
    <li class="todo-tasks-item">
        <h4 class="todo-inline">
          <a data-toggle="modal" href="#todo-task-modal">Welcome to the hotel California</a>
        </h4>
        <p class="todo-inline todo-float-r">Bob,
           <span class="todo-red">TODAY</span>
        </p>
     </li>
     <li class="todo-tasks-item">
        <h4 class="todo-inline">
           <a data-toggle="modal" href="#todo-task-modal">Talking 'bout my generation</a>
        </h4>
        <p class="todo-inline todo-float-r">Shane,
           <span class="todo-red">TODAY</span>
        </p>
     </li>
</ul>
```

On the above html all the info is obviously static. I know how to make ajax calls to fetch info from my db. What I don't really know how to do is displaying the corresponding tasks according to project_id whenever I click on a project.

I assume I need to make an ajax call and return the data along with some html and then do something like (dummy syntax)

```
 onclick(function() { 

   var tasksHTML = insert ajax call here 


 });
```

Not sure if this is the right approach, I'm new to js. Any suggestions?

UPDATE:

Here is a picture:

[image: todo]

In the picture, there is an active (clicked) project and on the right are the tasks that have that project id. How do I change the tasks list when I click a project?

Comment: So, when someone clicks "welcome to the hotel California" you want the project to display correct? And the project has already been loaded to the page, it is just hidden because it is not "active" right?

Comment: Actually, the opposite. The projects are all displayed. Welcome to the hotel California is a task of that project. I'll post a picture and update the post so it'ss more clear.

Comment: ok so if I click a project, making it active, you want to also pop up a modal with the to-do list. and you need to get the to-do list through an ajax call correct?

Comment: updated. I thinks its more clear now. :)

Comment: You may assign the db id to the html element as any data attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we need to give javascript a way to get the id so it can pass it to the PHP file that gets the tasks.

I assume you're binding JQuery click to the `<li>` so also include a data attribute and call it projectid. Or add this data attribute wherever the click method is bound.

```
<?php foreach ($projects as $project): ?>
        <li class="todo-projects-item" data-projectid="$project['id']">
          //.................
     <?php endforeach; ?>
```

If you are using JQuery do this in your .click method

```
$('.todo-projects-item').click(function(){
        //Get your project id from the data-attribute
        projectId = $(this).data('projectid');

        //run your ajax        
        $.post('phpfile.php', {projectId:projectId}, function(r){
            //your phpfile.php should echo a json of the tasks
            //see example below
            $('.class-of-the-task-div').html(r.html);
        }, 'JSON');

});
```

your php file can be something like this

```
$r['html'] = '<ul class="todo-tasks-content">
                  <li class="todo-tasks-item">
                  //....................Stuff
                  </li>
              </ul>';

echo json_encode($r);
```

Comment: jQuery has no `onclick` method and selector incorrect

Comment: Thanks a lot, silversunhunter. So my line of thought was actually correct, I just had no idea of how the syntax for this would be. I won't be able to code it today, I'll do it first thing tomorrow when I'm back to the office and I'll let you know if it works. Thanks again.

Comment: @Lberteh I fixed the selector